# How to solve error Component is not part of any NgModule or not imported correctly in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6, lazy-loading

This is error i am getting:-

```
<b>Error: Component Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.</b>
```

[image]

**I want my setup module to be lazily loaded but getting error like component is not part of module or the module has not been imported into your module**

```
//This is my app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LeaveService } from './EW_Leave/leave.service';
import { UtilsModule } from './EW_Utils/utils.module';
import { JobReferenceComponent } from '../app/EW_Utils/job-reference/job-reference.component'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { EWDashboardComponent } from './EW_Dashboard/ew-dashboard.component';
import { EWLoginComponent } from './EW_Login/ew-login.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StorageServiceModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    UtilsModule, LeaveModule, 
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, JobReferenceComponent, EWDashboardComponent, EWLoginComponent
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [LeaveService, Title],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {




}
```

//this is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EWDashboardComponent } from './EW_Dashboard/ew-dashboard.component';
import { EWLoginComponent } from './EW_Login/ew-login.component';
import { SetupDashboardComponent } from './EW_Setup/setup-dashboard/setup-dashboard.component';
import {CompaniesSetupComponent} from './EW_Setup/companies-setup/companies-setup.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: EWLoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: EWDashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'setup',

   loadChildren: './EW_Setup/setup.module#CustomersModule'

  },



]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule {


}
```

**THIS BELOW SETUP MODULE THAT I WANT TO BE LAZILY LOADED**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CompaniesSetupComponent } from './companies-setup/companies-setup.component';
import { SetupDashboardComponent } from './setup-dashboard/setup-dashboard.component';
import { BusinessUnitSetupComponent } from './business-unit-setup/business-unit-setup.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: SetupDashboardComponent},
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)],
  exports: [],
  declarations: []
})

export class SetupRoutingModule {


}
```

//THIS IS MY SETUP.MODULE.TS FILE

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UtilsModule } from '../EW_Utils/utils.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SetupDashboardComponent } from './setup-dashboard/setup-dashboard.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,UtilsModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,NgxSpinnerModule,SharedModule,SetupRoutingModule,Ng2SearchPipeModule,GrowlerModule,TextareaAutosizeModule
  ],
  declarations: [ SetupDashboardComponent, SidebarMenuComponent, CompaniesSetupComponent, BusinessUnitSetupComponent],
  providers:[CompaniesSetupService,GrowlerService,CommonApiService],
  entryComponents:[]
})
export class SetupModule { }
```

Comment: You forgot to add EWDashbardComponent to the declarations array of an NgModule. Try adding it to AppModule

Comment: @pixelbits: The `EWDashbardComponent` declaration seems to be present in the `app.module.ts`.

Comment: oh.. then I guess you're trying to access it from a lazy loaded module.  Add it to the lazy loaded module declarations array instead of in AppModule

Comment: Also this error comes when i click on the lazily module button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components declared from AppModule are not accessible by Lazy Loaded Modules (this is to protect the encapsulation of lazy loaded modules from outside component dependencies).

To access `EWDashboardComponent` from a lazy-loaded module, you need to either:

> 1. Declare the component from the lazy loaded module
> 2. Declare the component inside a widgets module, which is then imported by your lazy-loaded module (make sure the component is also
>      exported - meaning its also in the exports array)

If `EWDashboardComponent` is a shared component, I recommend option 2, because it follows Angular's Guidance on module types: https://angular.io/guide/module-types (see section on widget modules).

Comment: This means somewhere in the setup module is a reference to the `EWDashboardComponent`, probably in one of its components' templates - but the `EWDashboardComponent` is neither declared in nor imported into the setup module.

Comment: Right, should be simple to solve. Just add the component in the right place.

Comment: @pixelbits  if i define EWDashboardComponent inside my lazy loaded module ,i got error of defining component in two module.app module and setup, one thing i want to  tell that i am using setup component defined in lazy loaded module to be parents which is extended by other components in same lazy module(Setup Module).

Comment: You should declare the component in one module and import the module in all the places where you want to use the component

Comment: i solved the error, the error is because didn't defined components in a proper manner in my lazy loaded module. thank you guys for your help.

Comment: It was so funny I've been searching solutions for minutes. I just forgot to declare the component. Thanks for this haha

Answer (score 0):

I have a project of the following structure:

- **`gridster`** module contains **`@app/modules/gridster/angular-grid/angulargridComponent`**
- **`analytics`** module contains **`@app/modules/analytics/components/analytics-one/AnalyticsOneComponent`**

**Note:** Where my `gridster` module already using `analytics` module by importing it.

*I got the above issue when I tried to access the `angulargridComponent` inside `analytics` module due to the varied path and parent-child nestings.*

**Previously my analytics routing was:**

```
{ path: 'gross-profit', component: angulargridComponent}
```

**Instead of imported using, I changed to this and it worked:**

```
{ path: 'gross-profit', loadChildren: '@app/modules/gridster/gridster.module#angulargridModule' }
```

Where `angulargridModule` is the module class name inside `gridster` module and it contains only one component ie `angulargridComponent`